# iPhone - multiple text field search bar

Tags: iphone

I'm implementing a location based keyword search.  If anyone has seen Yelp's search bar, it is what i'm trying to do.  Basically once the search bar is clicked i want to provide one text field input for the keyword and the other for location. What UI element would I subclass?  How would I go about this?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to your question?  I'm trying to implement the exact same thing, but haven't had any luck in figuring it out.

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from just using two UITextField objects?

Comment: @Borg359 I have added my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also did a similar app, quite a while ago.
What I did in my app was I followed these steps, (I am only giving a brief description not the code part):

**Initial look:**

- I used search bar inserted into a navigation bar. (I did it programmatically in the `viewDidLoad` of my class).
- In my xib file of this class, I placed a view at the top and into it placed two `UITextFields` one below the other. I made this view hidden and shifted its y coordinates by the height of the view so that they became `-(viewHeight)`.

**Functionality Part**

- As soon as the user touches the search bar placed into the navigation bar, I made it hidden, unhidden the view with the text fields and shifted the y coordinates until they became 0 again.
- In the delegate methods of search bar, `- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar`  I returned NO, did the animation part (mentioned in the previous step) before returning NO from this method.
- I made my first text field the first responder so that the keyboard appears automatically.
- Now, when I am done filling data in both the text fields I reversed the animations and put the data filled into the text fields to the search bar.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Yelp's implementation looks to be a custom view with two UITextField objects, with a translation and scale animation to make it appear to be zoomed in from the top. A table view is added to the hierarchy after the animation is finished. The keyboard is invoked by making one of the text fields first responder.

BTW - generally speaking, composing UI elements together is preferred to subclassing.

Comment: I think they might add a new navigationItem to the navbar as well, since the title becomes "Search" and a cancel button appears.

Comment: that actually appears to be a new UINavigationBar altogether, it's faded in on top of the old one.